# Implementing a very special generic signature

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, signature

I'm currently building my own game engine based on Unity's decorator model. I have three classes (SceneStateManager (controls only one Scene at a time) > Scene > SceneLayer > GameObject > Component) that make up the scene hierarchy which all are basically the same except for the name and some smaller, very specific features. (Overriding methods will do it in this case)

All classes are initializable from the parent hierarchy level class type, and control a number of childs. As there is a lot of common functionality shared by the classes, I want to let them derive from a base class which groups the shared features to simplify the code.

The "super base class" `(ListJob<T>)` is a class that controls the childs, and until now, all of the beforementioned types derive from it to simplify at least that part. So the child handling itself does not need to be included in the code here as it is already working very well.

I now need to get a proper generic signature for the base class all of the scene hierarchy classes are to derive from in the future. My current solution does not compile with this error: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384252(v=vs.100).aspx

---

My current version of the generic signature and the SceneSystemJob class:

```
public abstract class SceneSystemJob<TItem, TParent> : ListJob<TItem>, IInitializable<TParent>  
    where TItem : IInitializable<SceneSystemJob<TItem, TParent>>
{  
    private TParent _Parent = default(TParent);

    public TParent Parent
    {
        get
        {
            return _Parent;
        }
        protected set
        {
            _Parent = value;
        }
    }

    // Implementation

    public void Initialize(TParent parent)
    {
        this.Parent = parent;
    }
}
```

SceneStateManager:

```
public class SceneStateManager // Controls only one Child and does not derive from super base class
```

Scene:

```
public class Scene : SceneSystemJob<SceneLayer, SceneStateManager>
```

SceneLayer:

```
public class SceneLayer : SceneSystemJob<GameObject, Scene>
```

GameObject:

```
public class GameObject: SceneSystemJob<Component, SceneLayer>
```

Component:

```
public abstract class Component : Manager, IInitializable<GameObject>
```

Interface IInitializable:

```
public interface IInitializable<TParent>
{  
    void Initialize(TParent parent);  
}
```

---

If you still need more code, please tell me.

Comment: This system looks way over designed. I would try to implement the components one by one and refactor out the common patterns (usually through TDD). That aside making a game engine is not a good way to make a game. They take a long time and offer little benefit outside of general knowledge.

Comment: @Romoku It's an already long-running project together with a friend and we stepped across this problem when I was refactoring the scene system. I could just implement everything by hand (as it was before), but this wouldn't comply with the DNRY-pattern.

The "over-designed" look comes from the attempt in putting as much code as possible into the SceneSystemJob, that's all. In fact, the code is very clean except that it does not build at the moment.

Also, it's not our primary goal to make a game (we will (small one), when it's done), we want to make a game engine.

Comment: I can't figure out what question this question is actually asking. "My code doesn't compile" isn't a question.

Comment: @EricLippert I'd like to know whether you've got an idea how I could change the generic signature to something working. At the moment I can't find a way out, I'm a little stuck in my head.

Comment: **Simplify, simplify, simplify.** Any time you make a generic object, ask yourself "could I replace this type argument with an interface or abstract base class?". Any time you make an interface or abstract base class, ask yourself "Am I ever going to have three or more otherwise unrelated implementations of this thing?"  Try to limit use of generics to the *embarrassingly generic*. A `List<T>` really can be *any* `T`. That you have complex constraints indicates that your type is not actually *generic*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know how to solve your problem other than by starting over with a much simpler system. This seems very over-engineered.

To explain why your code is wrong, look at this greatly simplified version of it:

```
public interface IInitializable<TParent> { }
public class SceneSystemJob<TItem>  
    where TItem : IInitializable<SceneSystemJob<TItem>>
{ }
public class GameObject : SceneSystemJob<Component> { } // Error here
public class Component : IInitializable<GameObject> { }
```

The error is that `Component` cannot be used as `TItem`.  Why not?  It seems plausible that this should work:

- `TItem` requires that it implement `IInitializable<SceneSystemJob<TItem>>`.
- `Component` implements `IInitializable<GameObject>`
- `GameObject` is a special kind of `SceneSystemJob<Component>>`
- Therefore `Component` meets the criterion of implementing `IInitializable<SceneSystemJob<Component>>`

The conclusion unfortunately does not follow from the premise unless `IInitializable<T>` is **covariant in T**. Since your real implementation has a method which takes *in* a T, it cannot be covariant in T.

Think about it this way. An `IInitializable<T>` is like a container that you can put a `T` into.  The constraint says "you need to give me a `TItem` such that it is a container that I can put **any** `SceneSystemJob<TItem>` into." You are giving it a container that you can **only** put `GameObject` into. Therefore the constraint is not met.

It's like the constraint says "I need a cage that can contain any animal" and you're handing it an aquarium. Well, that's a cage that can contain *any fish*, but the constraint doesn't say "I need a cage for *some* animal, your choice", it says it needs a cage for *any* animal.

I don't know how you fix this mess you've gotten yourself into other than starting over and not being so excessively generic.

Comment: Although I now have the laminations in there I wanted to get rid of by having the SceneSystemJob, the code has been simplified and compiles now. Thank you.